# Selenium can't seem to find and click a button on website? - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, find, element

I am trying to make software that automaticly collects data for me from `fiverr.com` website.

It searches for specific term, and then it should press `LOAD MORE` button at the end of page, and keep clicking it until it loads all the 'gigs'.

Anyway, I have good idea of how to make it keep clicking untill everything is loaded, but I cant seem to even click it.

This is my code for selecting the button and clicking it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn-standard-lrg btn-white"]').click()
```

And I keep getting following error:

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

If you go to: [fiverr gig url](https://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_in=everywhere&source=top-bar&query=explainer%20video&page=1&layout=lists&filter=new) and scroll down, you can see the LOAD MORE button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, using "layout-oriented" or "design-oriented" classes like `btn-standard-lrg` and `btn-white` is a bad practice.

Instead, there is a convenient locator ["by link text"](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text), use it:

```
load_more = driver.find_element_by_link_text("LOAD MORE")
```

Note how readable and simple it is.

---

You may also need to [wait until the "Load More" button would become visible](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
load_more = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'LOAD MORE')))
```

---

And, here is the complete code that would click "Load More" until it becomes invisible which would mean all posts are loaded:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_in=everywhere&source=top-bar&query=explainer%20video&page=1&layout=lists&filter=new")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        load_more = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'LOAD MORE')))
    except TimeoutException:
        break

    load_more.click()

for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.gig-item h3 a.gig-link-main"):
    print item.text.strip()
```

Comment: Tried that earlier aswell, i get following error:
Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Load More"}

Comment: @Miqro sure, it should be `LOAD MORE`, fixed. Worked for me.

Comment: @Miqro I've also provided a complete working solution to follow the "pagination".

Comment: This works great.. Thank you soooo much.. I love stackoverflow.. People helping out so fast . <3

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue given you are trying to interact with an element that is not visible in the page (you need to scroll down to the bottom of the page to visualise it)...

Try doing something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn-standard-lrg btn-white"]')

location = element.native.location[:y]

execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, #{location})")

element.click
```

or simply prior to clicking scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 10000)")
```

Comment: No, there is no need to scroll in this case. Check out the complete working code I've provided in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: In firefox you will be good, in chrome you will need to scroll... just a heads up.. ur selector is wrong, that's why you cant interact with it... the selector below is ugly (you can find a short cut later on), but is clickable: //*[@id="main-wrapper"]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/article/div[2]/a

Comment: Well, thanks for the follow-up. I've tried it in Chrome before posting - works for me. The `div.gig-item h3 a.gig-link-main` CSS selector matches the post titles which was intentional for the sake of demonstrating that all the results are loaded. Anyway, the main OP's problem here is to locate the Load More button and follow the pagination, which has been solved in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website some jiggery-pokery seems to be going on. From experience, I would suggest:

General:

1. Don't screen scrape information from 3rd party websites. If they change the website your code will break - perhaps contact the site to see if they have an API?
2. Always use the [PageObject](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) pattern as it'll keep your code DRY (think components rather than 'pages').

Specific:

3. Try selecting a parent element first and then work down to the element you want. This often leads you to the problem.
4. If you don't have any automatic retry configured in selenium you could be running that code before the element is made visible. As you can see from the error message, the element is there it's just not visible (I've got selenium experience but very little python so can't help you there :-( ).